# Padding of Text Input in Internet Explorer 11 does not work as expected

Tags: css, internet-explorer

In our web application we have input fields, which are styled by css.

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot, the styling works in Firefox (info data taken from Firebug), it also works in Google Chrome.

But in IE 11 the same field has this padding problem. The word "test" is not centered vertically.

So far I have tried without success:

```
box-sizing: border-box
extra line-height attribute
overflow-visible attribute
vertical-align
```

Thanks alot in advance

Edit:

I included a minimal CSS reset (https://perishablepress.com/a-killer-collection-of-global-css-reset-styles/), but it did not change.

I also included a screenshot from the ie developer tools. You can see all style definitions which take effect on the input field. I see no conflicting other style definition.

Edit:

I once again tried to use the "line-height" property. It did not work for me. The problem with this:

The input field has to have 34 pixels (22 input field (line-height) + 5x2 margin + 1x2 border). This works in FF and Google Chrome.  If I explicitly set the line-height to 22px, it does not change anything in IE. If I set the line-height to some other value (26px), it changes IE to the better, but it also changes the height of the input field in the other browsers (26 + 10 + 2) to 38px, so I cannot use it because the input height should not be other than 34 px.

[image]

Comment: did you use a CSS reset?

Comment: No, how looks a css reset that could help in this case?

Comment: A CSS reset may reset the default styling of the browsers, therefore only the styling you manually add will prevail. It will be consistent on all browsers.

Comment: Please check out this jsFiddle - it works fine on my IE11: http://jsfiddle.net/SfPju/737/  A CSS reset could work, but if so, it looks like it would be due to another stylesheet, not the browser default

Comment: Hello binderbound. Please see my edit of the original answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have found a solution:

A combination of "line-height" and "height" leads to the desired result:

```
.ni-ui-input {
    line-height: 27px;
    height:      22px;
}
```

If I use only "line-height: 27px", it helps me with repairing the IE view, but it changes the height of the input fields in the other browsers.

When I add the "height" attribute, the height of the input fields in the other browsers (Chrome, Firefox) will not change.

Comment: In your css code block in this answer you should include the **selector** to which you are applying these attributes. Are the height and line-height being applied to `input` or `input.some-ui-thing` or `.some-container` that encloses the input?

Comment: I apply it to "ni-ui-input".

Answer (score 0):

In your case, for IE you will need to set the `line-height` on the `input` correctly to vertically center the text in it .

Comment: Hello Arbel. Thank you for you post. The line-height does not work because it changes the height of the input field in the other browser. For details please see my 2nd edit of the question.

Comment: @WolfgangAdamec You will need to combine it with height as well.